# Connect to Postgres on Heroku with Django properly

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I'm new to Django and Heroku.
I'm confused about how I should connect to Postgres database on Heroku from my Django app considering the fact that all the credentials and `DATABASE_URL` could be changed.
Firstly, to connect to my Postgres on Heroku I started by using environment variables and hardcoded them in my Heroku dashboard.
Then I figured out that it is a bad practice because the values can be changed.

I checked [this guide by Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-heroku-postgres) where they recommend adding this to settings:

```
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600, ssl_require=True)
```

With that, I added my `DATABASE_URL` to my .env file - because otherwise, the URL will be empty. Now I can get all the correct database credentials in my DATABASE that are the same as in my dashboard. So halfway there.

Then I deleted all the hardcoded environment variables from my Heroku dashboard.

Then when I tried to `heroku run python src/manage.py migrate -a myapp` data, I received an error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

As I understand it, the problem is that it can't connect to the database (maybe because I deleted environment variables).

From what I saw on the internet - a lot of people in their guides on migrating to Postgres on Heroku use the hardcoded environment variables approach - which is a bad practice.
Otherwise, Heroku's guide doesn't show how specifically we should connect to the database with dynamically updated credentials.

Please advice.

Comment: Is `DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600, ssl_require=True)` the very last statement in your settings file? Are you sure you've deployed code that includes this line?

Comment: @Chris yes, it is the last statement. How is it important to be the last one?
And I forgot to push my latest code :) I did it - and resolved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. That doesn't necessarily have to be the last statement, but putting it last guarantees that you don't modify the value of `DATABASES['default']` somewhere else in the file. If you put it above the normal `DATABASES` configuration it will get overwritten, for example.